# Data, Feeds, Schema & Views module. Have I got the right idea?

Tags: views, feeds

I am thinking of using the following modules to import simple data from a csv file in order to be able to search by a couple of fields. I don't want the data to create new pages, I just want the data to be searchable and then displayed in the search results table format. To display the search results I am hoping to use the Views module.

Modules I am thinking of using:Data, Feeds, Schema, Views.

Have I got the right idea? Are these modules right for what I want to do? If so, where do I start?

By creating a new content type and the necessary feilds? Do I then Create a new table using the Data module? I guess I would then create a Feed and then finally a View. Is that correct? But where does the Schema module fit in?

Comment: You seem to have decided what modules you want to use without even knowing how they work.  I would suggest re-thinking your question so that you tell us specifically what you want to do, and what you have done so far to figure out how to accomplish that.

Comment: I updated my topic. Sorry